# A Non homogeneous Heat Equation have Solution Blows Up in Finite Time

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Suppose $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ is open bounded and have smooth boundary condition. Consider the problem
$$
u_t = \Delta u + u^3
$$
on $\Omega \times (0, T)$ with initial condition $u(x, 0) = u_0$ and boundary condition $\nabla u \cdot \nu = 0$ on $\partial \Omega \times (0, T)$. Suppose also that a smooth classical solution exist for the problem for some $T > 0$. The energy is defined as
$$
E(u) = \int_\Omega \frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2 - \frac{1}{4}u^4 dx.
$$
It is known that $\frac{d}{dt}E(u) \leq 0$ and there exists smooth initial condition $u_0$ such that $E(u_0) < 0$. **I want to show the solution $u$ can not be extended to infinite time. That is, the solution blows up in finite amount of time.** The hint ask us to consider the relation between $\frac{d}{dt} \int u^2$ and $E(u)$, which I am pretty sure is $$\frac{d}{dt} \int u^2 = \int_{\Omega} u^4 \,dx - 4E(u).$$ Combining this with the previous knowledge, we know at $t = 0$ the derivative has to be positive. However, I do not see why this would help us to solve the problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: You're almost there, You know that E is negative so you only need to find a lower bound for $\int u^4$ in terms of $\int u^2$. You should be able to do it with elementary inequalities.